# How do I allow a user from another domain to access files in domain

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a server called server7 where I want to give full access to a user that is on a different domain. How do I do this in windows server 2003?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to setup a [domain trust](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961481.aspx) then you can assign permissions the same way you normally do, just fully qualify the user as either `DOMAIN\user` or `user@DOMAIN`